# How does it calculate Solidity in opencv on black pixel contour?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

Solidity it is calculated like the ratio between area/convex hull area:

```
#calculating area from contour
area = cv2.contourArea(unicocnt)

#calculating hull and hull area
hull = cv2.convexHull(unicocnt) 
hull_area = cv2.contourArea(hull)

#solidity
solidity = float(area)/hull_area
```

calculating that for circle images i got all values close to 1 so i suppose that when i calculate area of contours i calculate area inside the circles with no consideration if inside are white pixel or not (contour is black)

image sample: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2b0JITFB4aHR0OWc/edit?usp=sharing

CODE:

```
nomeimg = 'Riscalate2/JPEG/e (5).jpg'

img = cv2.imread(nomeimg)

gray = cv2.imread(nomeimg,0)#convert grayscale adn binarize

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(6,6)) 
graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element) #imgbnbin

cv2.imshow('image',graydilate)
cv2.waitKey(0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(graydilate,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)   # binarize

imgbnbin = thresh
cv2.imshow('bn',thresh)
cv2.waitKey()

#element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(2,2))
#element = np.ones((11,11),'uint8')


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgbnbin, cv2.RETR_TREE ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))


# Take only biggest contour basing on area
Areacontours = list()
calcarea = 0.0
unicocnt = 0.0
for i in range (0, len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    #print("area")
    #print(area)
    if (area > 90 ):  #con 90 trova i segni e togli puntini
        if (calcarea<area):
            calcarea = area
            unicocnt = contours[i]

#calculating area from contour
area = cv2.contourArea(unicocnt)

#calculating hull and hull area
hull = cv2.convexHull(unicocnt) 
hull_area = cv2.contourArea(hull)

#solidity
solidity = float(area)/hull_area
```

**UPDATE**

I did it in this way:

```
ColoredArea = 0
for i in range(0,len(imgbnbin)):
    a = imgbnbin[i]
    for j in range (0, len(a)):
        if (cv2.pointPolygonTest(hull, unicocnt) >= 0):        
            if (getPixel(x,y) == black):
                ColoredArea = ColoredArea +1;
```

with this error:

```
if (cv2.pointPolygonTest(hull, unicocnt) >= 0):
TypeError: Required argument 'measureDist' (pos 3) not found
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. As you have stated the question, you have answered it by yourself.

Comment: problme is that, during calculation, is considered all circle with black and white pixel not only area of black pixel!

Answer (score 1):

Try a following algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
int ColoredArea = 0;
for (x=MinX to MaxX)
   for (y=MinY to MaxY)
        if (cv2.pointPolygonTest(hull, pt(x,y)) >= 0)
           if (getPixel(x,y) == black)
               ColoredArea++;
```

Comment: what do you mean for total area? these are my areas: area
8769.0
hull_area
8995.5
area m00
8769.0 m00 it consider all area with white and black pixel not only black!

Comment: Sorry about that - so this way won't work. I'll change my answer to just how you can write the algorithm yourself.

Comment: i'm not practical, i do not know how convert for (x=MinX to MaxX) this double for (y=MinY to MaxY) in python opencv

Comment: Doesn't the contour structure have it? Oh well. Set MinX and MinY to 0, and MaxX and MaxY to the width and height of the image, respectively.

Comment: cv2.pointPolygonTest(hull, unicocnt, _FALSE_) (or 0.. i don't know if it's bool or an int it expects.)

Comment: i have been tried but it requires a tuple and i got a <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Oh. Instead of unicont, you also need to provide a point - a pair of coordinates (x,y) that you create on the spot.

Comment: i converted numpy array unicocnt in tuple but it wants (x,y) one by one, unicocnt is a tuple of tuples like this: ((4,3),(7,8)...)

Comment: So I take it it worked after ryou figured how to put your counter x,y variables in a tuple :)

Comment: a tuple is not accesible like a list